# Cloudwatch Dashboard - Hide x-axis label from a bar graph

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, dashboard, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am currently using cloudwatch insights to plot a bar graph on dashboard by querying cloudwatch logs. The log data (which now will become label) is a bit sensitive to be shown up on the dashboard, however while plotting the bar graph continues to show the label.

Here's the insight query that I'm using.

```
filter @message like /Request class .* student /
| parse @message /Request class (?<classId>\S+) student (?<studentId>\S+)/
| stats count(*) as students, count_distinct(class) as classes by studentId
| sort students desc
| limit 20
```

Here studentId is something we don't want to show up on the graph.

I'm looking for either

1. Is there a way to hide or obfuscate the label in the dashboard?
2. If not, can we try modifying the insights query to help obfuscate the same ?